# Loading dates in Kendo UI Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I have a problem with setting a date field in the Kendo UI Grid, with ISO Date format (YYYY-MM-DD).

If I initialize the data source like this:

```
var gridDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: [{
        id: 1, description: 'Test 1', begin: '2012-10-01'
    }],
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: 'id',
            fields: {
                id: { type: 'number' },
                description: { type: 'string' },
                begin: { type: 'date' }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Then the date is displayed correctly:

[image: Initial]

But if i set it with the `data()` function of the data source like this:

```
gridDataSource.data([{
    id: 2, description: 'Test 2', begin: '2012-10-01'
}]);
```

Then the date is not displayed correctly and the inline editor is not working correctly:

[image: Setting with data()]

Here is the [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/r3lOOr3m2NrixkCzllHf) for this problem.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the culture kendo.culture('en-GB') to be the culture that you want it to be this will allow you to display the kendo date in what ever (culture) format you specified it to be. Then you can use the kendo.parseDate(variable, "yyyy/MM/dd"); just before you sent the date server side (This must be done for each value). Just watch the case (upper and lower) of the "yyyy/MM/dd" see [this](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/kendo#parseDate) link

Comment: Thanks. This is a workaround that I have considered, but I would like to avoid writing special code for each grid if I can

Comment: I ended up doing it this way, even though the behavior I am seeing is wrong in my point of view

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code snippet. Please check the format in column.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var gridDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                data: [{
                    id: 1, description: 'Test 1', begin: '2012-10-01'
                }],
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: 'id',
                        fields: {
                            id: { type: 'number' },
                            description: { type: 'string' },
                            begin: { type: 'date' }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            $('#grid').kendoGrid({
                dataSource: gridDataSource,
                scrollable: true,
                sortable: true,
                toolbar: ['create'],
                columns: [
            { field: 'id', title: 'ID', width: 'auto' },
            { field: 'description', title: 'Description', width: 'auto' },
            { field: 'begin', title: 'Begin', width: 'auto', format: "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" },
            { command: ['edit', 'destroy'], title: '&nbsp;', width: '172px' }
        ],
                editable: {
                    mode: 'inline',
                    confirmation: false
                }
            });

            $('#dataButton').click(function () {
                gridDataSource.data([{
                    id: 2, description: 'Test 2', begin: '2012-10-02'
                }]);
            });
        });

    </script>
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/LsIQhCvsTPssNf9TRmsn?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I want. I want the dates to be displayed with the local format, not the ISO Date Format. I only want the ISO format in the data, so that it is not dependent to the local date format. Maybe I want the impossible :-D

Comment: For that using JS, you have to get the client machine's timezone/culture. Based on this you can set the culture in kendo.Culture().

Comment: I'm already doing this. My demo is using the standard 'en-US' culture. If i change the culture with `kendo.culture('de-DE');`, and the column format to `"{0:d}"` so it is displayed according to the cultire, I still have the same problem

Comment: I will try to resolved your issue. Once i will get the solution i will get back to you. I will set the culture 'de-DE' in my application. Then i will try to resolved your issue.